# Detecting user previously signed up with Google?

Tags: discussion, login, google

When a user has signed up with Google, by clicking the big red button on https://stackoverflow.com/users/signup for example, that user might associate their email address "hendry@example.com" with that sign up.

However if the user then tries a fresh login and perhaps forgets they initially registered by pressing the Google red button, they might have a negative user experience; An incorrect password, when in fact no password was set.

[image: Stackoverflow login page]

My question is there a better user experience than this "The email or password is incorrect" error message? Couldn't the site lookup the email address and then redirect the user to using a Google login? If that is the case, why doesn't stack overflow do that?

P.S. I am aware the workaround is to reset your password, but I find that very clumsy.

Comment: That seems to provide anyone with less than perfect intentions with more information than they should get. "Yes, they do have an account, and they use their Google login to log into the site"

Comment: So you're saying the UX is bit suboptimal because of security concerns? People can discover if you use the site via Forgotten password form, no?

Comment: Forgotten password should give the user the same results no matter if the user/email is in the system or not.

Comment: There really isn't. Login pages have long been a battle of user experience vs user privacy/security. Doing pretty much *anything* on that page when you've entered incorrect credentials or used the wrong credential type would give away that you have an account here, and worse that your email address is valid (time to start spamming that email).

Comment: Ok, I understand the security concern. IMAGINE there wasn't a security concern, wouldn't it be conceivably a better UX to login the user using the Google flow? It would just be a email address lookup on the backend, right?